# ArrayIndexOutOf BoundsException while trying to read pixels from an image

Tags: java, arrays, exception, bufferedimage, indexoutofboundsexception

i am getting an ArrayIndexoutOfBoundsException while trying to read pixels from image . the code returns the pixel values for some images and not for other images..i tried searching the net, and most of them referred to reading from 0 to n...

The code is given below..any help would be truly appreciated..

i tried writing saving the image in bi,and it gets saved..so bi is never getting null value..
and my image dimension is always 125*150.. 
i tried printing the values in inputFace,but in  those images that doesn't give pixel values,i am not even getting any output while printing... 
Doesn't array get initialized with 0 as soon as memory is allocated??

And thanks in advance

```
private double[] getImageData(String imageFileName)  {

        BufferedImage bi = null;
        double[] inputFace = null;


        try{
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFileName));

        }catch(IOException ioe){

                    ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bi != null){
                       int imageWidth = bi.getWidth();
                       int imageHeight = bi.getHeight();
                       inputFace = new double[imageWidth * imageHeight];

                         bi.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,inputFace);


                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Null in bi");
                }


                return inputFace;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried without preallocating inputFace? Doing `inputFace = bi.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,inputFace);`

Comment: i had tried that too,,but its not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't taking into account the number of bands per pixel - each pixel is made up of a number of bands (channels, e.g. Red, Green, Blue, Alpha for images of TYPE_INT_ARGB) depending on the image type.  The array you're allocating needs to be (pixel width * pixel height * number of bands) in size:

```
int numBands = bi.getData().getNumBands();
inputFace = new double[imageWidth * imageHeight * numBands];
```

This will give you an array containing all the values for each channel of each pixel.